# Unable to copy data from Azure Germany Storage account using Azure Data Factory

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory, azure-storage-account

I have a Storage account in Azure Germany (the sovereign version, not the public cloud) and I want to copy its data to Azure global public storage account using Azure Data Factory.

But Azure Data Factory throws this error:

> Invalid storage connection string provided to '***UnknownLocation***'. Check the storage connection string in configuration. No valid combination of account information found.

I can't use "AzCopy" because I want schedule this process.

Scenario - Copy data from "*.blob.core.cloudapi.de" to "*.blob.core.windows.net" using Azure Data Factory

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume the connection to the German sovereign cloud is the one failing. If so try editing that linked service in ADF and adding the following to the end of the connection string:

```
;EndpointSuffix=core.cloudapi.de;
```

This answer is based upon ADF [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/connector-azure-blob-storage?#account-key-authentication) and storage [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-configure-connection-string?#create-a-connection-string-with-an-endpoint-suffix).